# How to Run a file with a variable name in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a code that will rename an RDP file downloaded at the Temp folder, and I want the script to run that file too, the new name of the file is a variable, so how can I call both the directory and the file name as variables in a Run command.

I have tried this code but I know something is wrong (dir is the path variable and sNewFile is the file name variable):

`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").run "& dir & "\" & sNewFile &"`

Update: I edited the line but now it is opening the directory folder but not running the file:
`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").run " "&dir&" ""\"" "&sNewFile&" "`

Comment: Check your quotes, they are off (backslash is not the way to escape quotes in vbscript. You should double the quotes to escape them.

Comment: If I change it to : CreateObject("WScript.Shell").run "& dir & ""\"" & sNewFile &"    I get the error:      Type mismatch: '[string:"& dir &"]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to run the file from a different directory, I now changed the command to run from the files directory with just the file's name as a variable:

```
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
shell.CurrentDirectory = dir2
shell.Run sNewFile
```

Thank you all for the help and suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
Dim Fso, WshShell
Set WshShell   = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set Fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
windirpath=wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%SystemDrive%")
ParentFolder  = FSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
sParentFolder = ParentFolder & "\"
TempFolder = windirpath & "\TEMP"

FileName1 = "A.RDP"
FileName2 = "B.RDP"

Fso.MoveFile TempFolder & "\" & FileName1, TempFolder & "\" & FileName2

WshShell.run TempFolder & "\" & FileName2
```